# Radio tax already paid by landlord, tenant still getting bill

Tags: germany, taxes

I am living in Berlin for past one year. I was living in a shared apartment for 7-8 months. Then my landlord was paying radio tax for us. He gave me the number for it.

I entered that [here](https://www.rundfunkbeitrag.de/antworten/index_ger.html) along with the number I got through post after city registration.

I recently moved to my new apartment and registered it. Then I got a letter from ARD saying that I have to pay for the entire year.

My question is how to avoid paying the amount for my previous apartment, since it is already paid by the landlord. I am ready to pay it for the new apartment because no one else is paying for it.

Answer (score 1):

They should only charge you for any months **before** you registered with the landlords number (if any).

The date they recieved the registration is important.

If you were living there from January to August and registered with the Landlords number in January: you shouldn't have to pay anything.

Should they be charging for months before you arrived in Germany, then supply them proof when you entered Germany.

Adding the specific dates to your question would be helpfull, because without those a precise answer cannot be given.